# Strong Parameters: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

Lets say I have a PostsController and I have a Post model and Comment model. I'm allowing comments to be made on a Post, so on my posts/show I put the following

```ruby
 # routes.rb
 resource :post do 
   member do 
      post :add_comment
    end
 end

 # post.rb
 has_many :comments

 # comment.rb
 belongs_to :post
```

```erb
<%= form_with(model: @post, url: add_comments_post_path) do |form| %>
   <%= form.text_area :body %>
<% end %>
```

```erb
# posts_controller

def add_comment
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.comments.create(params[:comment])
end

private 
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
```

I tried adding `:comment` on permit but it raises `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`

Comment: Check the server log, you'll see the parameters of the request, you have to replicate that. What to require/permite depends on the actual form inputs, it's hard to tell since you are not showing the inputs. If you are not sure, do one of those form submissions and copy here log of that request.

Comment: is params {comment => {:body => "message}, id => 1}

Comment: @Berimbolo can u post error log ?

Comment: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the Strong Parameters ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError fixed like so:

```ruby
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, comment_attributes: [:body])
```

Comment: if it solved your issue you can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you have to do:

```rb
post = Post.find(params[:id])
post.comments.create(comment_params)
```

and permit it like:

```rb
private
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

Comment: I tried, adding that second strong param but im forbidden attributes error on log

Comment: update the question, add the controller code and the request log

Comment: Also, there's a full rails official guide about what you are doing, I'd suggest you read this first https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html (it's a blog sample app with posts and comments, all code is there with steps and explanations)

Comment: I see you copied the code of your controller, it's not what I put in this answer, the first part is the add_comment action and the second is the strong parameters part. I'm not sure what did you try.

Comment: I updated the controller the way you did and the form as well. Still same error, params[:comment] is still an error

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read the rails guide link I pasted in a previous comment. You have all the explanations and steps by step on how to do almost exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Okay I got it, turns out i need to define comment_attributes [:body] insted of comment: [:body]